# Pig udf on Filter

Tags: apache-pig, udf

I have a use-case in which i need to take in the date of a month to return the previous month's last date.

```
Ex: input:20150331 output:20150228
```

I will be using this previous month's last date to filter a daily partition(in pig script).

```
B = filter A by daily_partition == GetPrevMonth(20150331);
```

I have created an UDF(GetPrevMonth) which takes the date and returns the previous month's last date.But unable to use it on the filter.

```
ERROR:Could not infer the matching function for GetPrevMonth as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast.
```

My udf takes tuple as input.
Googling it says that UDF cannot be applied on filters.
Is there any workaround? or am i going wrong somewhere?

```
UDF:public class GetPrevMonth extends EvalFunc<Integer> {

    public Integer exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        String getdate = (String) input.get(0);
        if (getdate != null){
        try{
            //LOGIC to return prev month date
        }
```

Need help.Thanks in advance.

Comment: You should accept Balduz's answer unless you feel that it isn't satisfactory (to me it seems right)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can call a UDF in a `FILTER`, but you are passing a number to the function while you expect it to receive a `String` (`chararray` inside Pig):

```
String getdate = (String) input.get(0);
```

The simple solution would be to cast it to `chararray` when calling the UDF:

```
B = filter A by daily_partition == GetPrevMonth((chararray)20150331);
```

Generally, when you see some error like `Could not infer the matching function for X as multiple or none of them fit`, 99% of the time the reason is that the values you are trying to pass to the UDF are wrong.

One last thing, even if it is not necessary, in a future you might want to write a pure `FILTER` UDF. In that case, instead of inheriting from `EvalFunc`, you need to inherit from `FilterFunc` and return a `Boolean` value:

```
public class IsPrevMonth extends FilterFunc {
    @Override
    public Boolean exec(Tuple input) throws IOException {
        try {
            String getdate = (String) input.get(0);
            if (getdate != null){   
                //LOGIC to retrieve prevMonthDate

                if (getdate.equals(prevMonthDate)) {
                    return true;
                } else {
                    return false;   
                }
            } else {
                return false;
            }
        } catch (ExecException ee) {
            throw ee;
        }
    }
}
```